# Javascript dynamic input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if there is a plugin which will be setting mask to the input, depending on which I have already input there.

For example if I set mask of an input to numbers from 0-4, and then write '1' to the input, I want be able to write only '0', '2', '3', '4'. 
I have already tried following mask plugins:

```
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
```

but I only can achieve that, the whole input clear after write character, or the caret goes to the back of the input, or I'm not able to write anything.
Here is my attempts to achieve what I want:

```
jQuery.mask.definitions['x'] = '[123456789]';
jQuery('#inputLabel').mask("x, x, x, x, x, x, x");
```

and if I input something to the input I tried this:
setting mask one more time

```
jQuery.mask.definitions['x'] = returnDistinctTab(); //returnDistinctTab return tab without character which I have already input to the input.
var text = jQuery("#inputLabel").val();
text.replace('_', 'x');
jQuery('#inputLabel').mask('text');
```

If someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong, or knows mask which will be suitable for my case, I will be very grateful!!

Comment: if I understand you correctly, that plugin does something else from what you're describing. You're looking for a way to limit the input to only unique numbers, while that plugin makes some readable template for entering numbers (it's close, but not exactly the same).

Comment: @yuvi yes it's what I want to achieve. I want to achieve dynamic input mask. If I set mask to "0123" and wrote 0, mask should change to "123", then if I wrote 1, mask should change to "23" and the text in input shouldn't disappear and caret shouldn't go to the end of the text. With this plugin I'm not able to re-set the mask without loosing what I have already wrote in input, or going caret to the end of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`oninput` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput), and write a simple function that enforces unique values from a list:

```html
<script>
    function verifyInput(txt, mask) {
        var res = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
            var char = parseInt( txt[i] );
            if (mask.indexOf(char) > -1 && res.indexOf(char) === -1)
                res += char;

        }
        return res;
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="unique-numbers" oninput="this.value=verifyInput(this.value, [0, 1, 2, 4])" />
```

It'll probably be faster than a jQuery plugin, and also easier to maintain (you're not limited to anything, really).

Comment: Looks that this is what I want to achieve! I will check this out in my code and if it works (in any browser I need) I will accept it as an answer :)

Comment: @LubiePice browser compatibility for `oninput` is [pretty solid](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp), when even IE9 supports it. If you have to work with older browsers, take a look at [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which might help you make it work

Comment: I check this out it works fine with Mozilla 31/Chrome/IE 8+ and it's fine for me! One more time Thank You very much!

Comment: I believe `char in mask` should be `mask.indexOf( char ) > -1`. `char in mask` checks whether the `mask` array has an index with the value of `char`, not whether it has a value with the value of `char`. Your example accidentally works here, because the values in `mask` happen to coincide exactly with its indices.

Comment: @DecentDabbler you're absolutely right, fixed, thanks!